# Convert periods (hundredth of a second) r

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a vector of the following form:

```
data$Time[1:10]

[1] 0:00.00 0:00.01 0:00.02 0:00.03 0:00.04 0:00.05 0:00.06 0:00.07 0:00.08 0:00.09
573394 Levels: 0:00.00 0:00.01 0:00.02 0:00.03 0:00.04 0:00.05 0:00.06 0:00.07 0:00.08 0:00.09 0:00.10 0:00.11 0:00.12 0:00.13 0:00.14 ... 9:59.99
```

notice that this is a factor form

```
class(data$Time)

factor
```

I've tried the following

```
hms(data$Time[1:10])

[1] "0S" "1S" "2S" "3S" "4S" "5S" "6S" "7S" "8S" "9S"
```

it sees the 1/100 of a second as a second! same thing for

```
period_to_seconds(hms(data$Time[1:10]))

[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I need to be able to extract the time (with the require accuracy) to be able to subtract and calculate periods. Notice that these files will extend to few hours. So a solution that is good for HH:MM:SS.00 will be appreciated

another approach that only works if you have data that is either H M S or M S solely is the following:

```
Test <- c('03:5.05', '1:03.05.05')
tmp <- strptime(as.character(Test),"%H:%M:%OS")
tmp
[1] NA NA
tmp <- strptime(as.character(Test),"%M:%OS")
tmp
[1] "2016-04-30 00:03:05.05 CDT" "2016-04-30 00:01:03.05 CDT
```

(The hours had to be removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jorg's answer. I think I was able to solve my problem. The files I am working with extend for few hours (with each point representing 0.01 sec). So I split the vector (data$Time) and applied the MS script for the first 360000 points and the HMS script for what following:

```
options(digits.secs = 2)

tmp1 <- strptime(as.character(data$Time[1:360000]),"%M:%OS")
tmp2 <- strptime(as.character(data$Time[-(1:360000)]),"%H:%M:%OS")

tmp1_numeric <-as.numeric(strftime(tmp1,'%OS'))+60*as.numeric(strftime(tmp1,'%M'))+60*60*as.numeric(strftime(tmp1,'%H'))
tmp2_numeric <-as.numeric(strftime(tmp2,'%OS'))+60*as.numeric(strftime(tmp2,'%M'))+60*60*as.numeric(strftime(tmp2,'%H'))

tmp_numeric <- c(tmp1_numeric, tmp2_numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## set option to use digits for seconds
options(digits.secs = 2)
## convert your factor to a string and then to Posix format
tmp <- strptime(as.character(data$Time),'%H:%M:%OS')
## convert it to a numeric (unit seconds)
as.numeric(strftime(tmp,'%OS'))+60*as.numeric(strftime(tmp,'%M'))+60*60*as.numeric(strftime(tmp,'%H'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Jorg. Unfortunately there is an issue with the solution you proposed if the data have even two points: one with HMS and the other with only MS. Please see bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ms function in lubridate package to read only the minutes and seconds.

```
Test <- c('0:00.02', '9:59.99')

library(lubridate)
Test %>% ms() %>% period_to_seconds()

[1]   0.02 599.99
```